# How to detect accordion element height?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to detect the height of the accordion when the user open it. I'm using angular bootstrap UI.

I have something like this:

```
<div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
    <accordion id='accordion' close-others="false">
        <accordion-group is-open="false">
            <accordion-heading >                  
                <h2 ng-click='open()'>title</h2>
            </accordion-heading>
            <div>
                <div>
                    lots of content here…..
                </div>
            </div>
        </accordion-group>          
    </accordion>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
     $scope.open=function(){
        var Height = $('#accordion div').height();
         //The problem is the height is the accordion title div instead of the whole div
         //because it takes time to expand the accordion. 
         //I need to know the entire accordion height 
         //instead of just accordion title height.
    }
}]);
```

Can anyone help me about it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can achieve this in a tricky way:

```
$scope.open=function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    var Height = $('#accordion').height();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your div and get the height with

```
$scope.open=function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        var Height = $('#youDivId').height();
    }
}
```